# additional this->here security still necessary?

Tags: security, cakephp

in some CakePHP apps you can find

```
preg_replace('/["\']/', '”', addslashes(strip_tags($thisHere)))
```

like in http://noserub.googlecode.com/svn/branches/development/app/app_controller.php
where $this->Controller->here is "additionally secured" in some way

a) what exactly is/was the problem with it? could it hurt the application? I cannot imagine that " or ' could harm it in any way.

b) is it still useful? or are all "possible dangers" already fixed in the more current cake versions?
if so: are there any use case scenarios where one could actually test the possible issues?

NOTE: in 2.0 it has moved to "$this->request->here" - but still contains the current absolute url (/controller/action/..).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the method is totally unnecessary as the form helper should escape automatically.
and for all other use cases you should just escape the url.

citing
http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/39e1024efe918e66/efb8ee0bea7bcd1

Answer (score 0):

I think the comment above the line in question is pretty clear:

```
/**
 *  Don't you EVER remove this line else you will make the whole 
 *  application a swiss cheese for XSS!
 *  We often call echo $this->here in our form actions and this would
 *  be exactly where the injection would take place.
 */
$this->here = preg_replace('/("|\')/', 'â€', addslashes(strip_tags($this->here)));
```

Comment: i was assuming that such a "fix" would have been implemented long time ago in the cake core. but I guess not everybody uses $this->here in the forms then... but it also means: everybody who does use it without this fix has automatically an unsafe application. quite disturbing!